# Adding files to an application c#

Tags: c#

I have some files and I want that files to be copied to a folder in temporary folder when running my application. My application is written in c#. How can I add these files to my application so that when I run my app these files will get copied to temporary folder?

I have tried by adding the files as Resources, but still I have to keep those files manually. Is there any way to embed the files in my application so that when I run it will get copied to temporary folder?

Thanks

Comment: Typically, this is done by using an **installer** that installs your application and also any support files it needs.

Comment: Could this be done by adding the files to the project and setting their "Copy to output directory" as "Copy Always"?

Comment: Right click on Application folder of setup and click on add and file. whenever you install your app these file will be copied in default location of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is.

If you right click 'properties' for the files in question, you'll see that you can change the "build action", set this to "content" and then set "copy if newer". They will then be placed in output folder, in the same structure of folders that they are in, in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to embed files in your .exe so that they will be automatically copied when the exe is run. (You can set properties in the solution explorer so that they are copied when the exe is *compiled* as @noon silk has suggested. Similarly you can use an installer to install an application along with some files, but again they are not copied when the application is *run*, only when it is installed).

To embed files in an exe so they are copied out when it **runs**, you can do this:

- add the file to your project in the solution explorer using `Add Existing Item`. As you add them, on the file open dialog, click the little down arrow at the right end of the `Add` button, and choose the `Add as Link` option. Instead of copying the current file into your project (so you have to manually update it each time it changes) this will just reference your original file, and copy the latest version into your app each time it is compiled.
- get properties on the added file in solution explorer and set the type to `Embedded resource`
- add code to your app to write the file to disk. use `Assembly.ExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream()` to read the data into a byte array, and then save that data to disk in the location of your choice by writing the array to a `FileStream`.

For example:

```
Stream dataStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.SomeFolder.DataFile.dat");
byte[] fileData = new byte[dataStream.Length];
dataStream.Read(fileData, 0, (int) dataStream.Length);

using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\RealFileOnDisk.dat", FileMode.Create))
    outStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
```